# Comparing Dates with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, arrays, date

I am trying to compare dates using comparison operators such as => or <. First thing I don't know if this is possible due to the "/". I've been searching for a couple hours no and haven't found anything that allows you to check to see if dates match. I have been able to do this for a single date but haven't found a way to do this for multiple dates.

Since I am using CodeIgnitor my code look a little something like this.

```
$date = ('9/28/2013');
$listings = $this->db->get('listings', array('listing_end_date <=', $date))->result_array();
print_r($listings); exit;
```

Yes, I am aware that `$date` is a string but even as a Date variable I could not get this to work for me.

Comment: So weird thing is it doesn't matter what I input for date I get a single array back with the same data every time even though multiple rows have the same date... Do I have my get correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change date format to `YYYY-mm-dd` as :

```
$date = '9/28/2013';
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

[Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your database is properly architected, the proper date format in MySQL is YYYY-MM-DD. This means you will want to revise your date format as such.

```
$date = '2013-09-28';
```